# shell script check `service httpd restart` command status?

Tags: linux, apache, shell, unix, sh

I am writing a shell script and here is the snippet ..

```
sudo service httpd restart   --- ( 1)  

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

     # Now configure php.ini using sed command 
     sudo sed -i 's_;date.timezone =_date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"_' /etc/php.ini 

  # Now restart the httpd server again 

  sudo service httpd restart  ---- This statement throws error
```

When I ran above script then I got error `Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address` at second `sudo service httpd restart` statement.

I doubt it is because when first time `sudo service httpd restart` runs ,  before it **finishes** completely second 'sudo service httpd restart' runs.

So how can I test surely If first `sudo service httpd restart` finishes then only rest of the code execute.

I hope I am understandable ..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Forget the `[` giving:

```
if sudo service http restart; then
    # stuff
    if sudo service http restart; then
        echo ok
    else
        # error handling for second service failure
    fi
else
    # error handling for first failure
fi
```

Commands are true if their return status is zero, false otherwise. Shell commands also must terminate before the next line is called.

It is possible, in principle, that `service` does stuff in the background and exits before completion. In practice, it doesn't because that would really screw things up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the command backgrounds. If so, you could check if your command is still to be found in the process list:

```
// ... your code ...
c=1
while [[ c -gt 0 ]] 
do
    c=`ps l | grep -c "service httpd restart"`
done
service httpd restart
```

Comment: if `service` command is not in backgroud then will `if []` statement will return 0 only when `httpd` restart completely ?

Comment: No, this way it will only check if the command is still running. If it finished (either way) the while loop will end and the next restart will happen. @msw surely has posted the better solution if you need to handle errors.